# Pipe Command Not Working In Windows

Tags: linux, windows, appveyor

`type coverage/lcov.info | coveralls/bin/coveralls.js`
I used above command in appveyor.yml file for generating coverage in coveralls, but there is one problem,Pipe Command is not working in Windows. Please suggest an alternative command for Windows.

Comment: Why is this tagged `c#`?

Comment: Your problem is not the pipe, your problem is what engine is executing your script. In windows, by default, `.js` files are not handled by `node` unless you change file association or include the executable in the command line

Answer (score 1):

What did you expect to happen?  Javascript files such as `coveralls.js` are not an executable file type on Windows.   So while pipe does work on Windows, the text to the right of the pipe needs to be an executable command.

Maybe you meant something like this:

`jscript coveralls/bin/coveralls.js < coverage/lcov.info`